# .NET Framework, .NETportable and .NET Standard

Tags: .net, .net-standard

What is actually the difference between these three? I understand .NET portable is obsolete, pretty much, but what about the other two.

Comment: The .NET Framework is what you have installed on your machine, it executes your program.  .NETStandard can be useful to target in a library project, some odds that the library can be used on another machine.   Like an Apple iPhone.  Same thing as PCL did, you can only use a subset of types, the kind that port well to another operating system or CLR version.  Like System.String but not System.Windows.Forms.Form.  Different from PCL is that you don't have to pick a list of target platforms anymore, that didn't work so well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Standard is an interface while .NET Framework is an implementation of that interface. NET Core is another implementation of NET Standard. This makes it so that when creating libraries you can target NET Standard instead of any of the above mentioned implementations making the library available to both NET Framework and NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it looks to me that .NETStandard is the formal standard to which .NETFramework, and lately .NETCore, adheres.

To quote from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

The .NET Standard is a formal specification of .NET APIs that are intended to be available on all .NET implementations.

The .NET Framework 4.6 implements .NET Standard 1.3, which means that it exposes all APIs defined in .NET Standard versions 1.0 through 1.3. Similarly, the .NET Framework 4.6.1 implements .NET Standard 1.4, while .NET Core 1.0 implements .NET Standard 1.6.